# Mostrar el nombre de mi equipo con QT

Tags: c++, qt

Hola en una aplicación que la hecho para usarla solamente yo quiero mostrar el nombre de mi equipo. Se que se puede mostrar el nombre del usuario de lsiguiente modo:

```
QDir::homePath()
```

Pero lo que quiero es mostrar el nombre de mi equipo en mi programa es posible?

Comment: ¿Para qué sistema operativo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El nombre del equipo es una característica dependiente de sistema operativo, según el que estés usando necesitarás incluir determinadas cabeceras y usar ciertas funciones.

Por ejemplo, en Windows debes usar [`GetComputerName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724295(v=vs.85).aspx) o [`GetComputerNameEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724301(v=vs.85).aspx) disponibles en `Winbase.h` (incluida desde `Windows.h`) y en Linux deberás usar [`gethostname`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/gethostname) disponible en `unistd.h`.

Por otro lado, Qt es multiplataforma y ofrece facilidades para tareas comunes independientes de plataforma, así que tal vez puedas usar [`QHostInfo::localHostName()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qhostinfo.html#localHostName).